# Redirecting domain (diff domain, same directory) using htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect to a different domain keeping the directory, so for example:

```
example.org/user/test
```

would be directed to:

```
example.com/user/test
```

I'm using Zend Framework, so this is what I have in my .htaccess:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

php_value "short_open_tag" "on"
```

But what I'm getting from the browser is:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, cgiadmin@yourhostingaccount.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Can anyone help me with this issue please? why is this happening?
is my .htaccess wrong?

Comment: What did you find in your http error logs?

Comment: What is this rule for? >> `RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]` You want all request to be redirected to `index.php`?

Comment: @Omega, that part comes together with Zend's defaults

Comment: Do you still get the error if you remove the `SetEnv ...` and `php_value ...` lines?